# Capture a match with Regex on Python and Assign the captured string value to variable

Tags: python, regex, string, list

Just started learning python/regex.

I have error log file in which I want to capture the strings that match specific patterns, and create a list from it. There is one error per line. I have the datetime portion down. I need to extract 'company' and 'errorline', assign them to variables, append to my nested list.

The error lines look something like this:

`2013-02-02 12:20:15 blahblahblah=123214, moreblah=1021, blah.blah.blah, company=201944, errorline=#2043`

```
f = open("/path/error.log","r")

errorlist = [["datetime","company","errorline"]]     #I want to append to nested list

for line in f:
    datetime = line[:19]
    company = re.search(r"=[0-9]{6},",line)
    company = company.group[1:-1]                    #to remove the '=' and ','
    errorline = re.search(r"#[0-9]{1,}",line)
    errorline = errorline.group()[1:]

    errorlist.append([datetime,company,errorline])
```

I know that this code does not work because I can't assign the .group() to a variable.

Please help!

Comment: It seems to be a log file with a very rigorous format. I think you should split each line with a comma and after split the two last items with a `=`

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
company = re.search(r'=([0-9]{6}),',line).group(1)
errorline = re.search(r'#([0-9]{1,})',line).group(1)
```

note the parentheses, and call to `.group`. Also, you may do it all together:

```
company, errorline = re.search(r'=([0-9]{6}),.*?#([0-9]{1,})',line).groups()
```

Comment: Hello @behzad.nouri
I have done as you said, but I still get the following error.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @so123 that means that specific line does not match the pattern

Answer (score 0):

[re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)

Classically, your code for the match should be:

```
match= re.search(r'(\d+)', 'abc 123 def')
if match:
    digits = match.group(1)
else:
    # react to no match
```

You can also compact both matches in your example into one ([Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dB0hH6/1)) and can be seen here:

```
>>> s='2013-02-02 12:20:15 blahblahblah=123214, moreblah=1021, blah.blah.blah, company=201944, errorline=#2043'
>>> match=re.search(r'^.*company=(\d+)\D+(\d+)', s)
>>> match.group(1)
'201944'
>>> match.group(2)
'2043'
```

so then the match part of your code becomes something like:

```
match=re.search(r'^.*company=(\d+)\D+(\d+)', line)
if match:
    company=match.group(1)
    errorline=match.group(2)
    # do whatever with company and errorline
else:
    # react to an unexpected line format...
```

Comment: you cannot call `.group` unless the regex has capturing parentheses. above code throws regardless of having a match or not.